FFT Signal Analysis - Hardware Configuration
I have began working on a project that entails using an 1MHz Unipolar 12-bit ADC that has two inputs connected to a buffer opamp. One channel on the opamp is inverting, and the other is non-inverting. The two inputs to the opamp are connected to two different monopole antennas.
To analysis the radio frequency signals, I developed a C++ application that will parse one channel of the 12-bit ADC samples and plot them to a graph.
Based on the graph output, is there any suggestions on what improvements I can make, as far as, DSP techniques and/or hardware improvements? Does the noise floor look low enough? What about the phasing plot... seems there is a bunch of noise there, not sure if my C++ algorithms are performing correctly.
I would like to be able to use signal tracking techniques to source the signals that are found, in order to do so, I understand that accurate magnitudes need to be determined. I also understand that some of these magnitude values need to be calculated from the phasing portion of the signal, so a little concerned about the Phase plot.


There's a lot in play here. What a "good" noise floor is depends on your hardware. Are you sampling directly from the ADC? Is there an amplifier somewhere with a known noise figure? If you had a schematic of your hardware and what some of the parameters are, you could compare the results to the expected values. Also, recommend that you start testing using single tones and the move on to more complex waveforms.
